# Sliding Child WIndow not working in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I used translatetransform to slide my child window but I think there's something wrong with my xaml code.  It's not the window is sliding but inside the window is sliding (or the grid).

This is my Child Window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SAMPLE.ChildWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
  x:Name="HomeWindows"
  Title="HomeWindow" Height="348" Width="440" Loaded="HomeWindows_Loaded">
  <Window.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform />
  </Window.RenderTransform>
  <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="SlaydAndFeyd" >
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HomeWindows"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" From="50" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.4" />
    </Storyboard>
  </Window.Resources>
```

and then for my function, calling the storyboard:

```
    public void SlaydAndFeyds()
    {
        (FindResource("SlaydAndFeyd") as Storyboard).Begin(this);
    }
```

and now in the Main Window code:

```
namespace SAMPLE
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ChildWindow NewChildWindow = new ChildWindow();

    private void btnShowChild_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewHomeWindow.Owner = this;
        NewHomeWindow.Show();
    }

    private void btnSlideChild_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       NewHomeWindow.SlaydAndFeyds();
    }
```

or anyone have an idea how can I slide my child window?

Answer (score 1):

The RenderTransform in that example will affect the contents of the window, not the window itself.

To move the window, adjust the Left/Top attributes using an EventTrigger. I'm taking a guess that you want to slide it left by 50 pix or so over 4 seconds, adjust the figures to suit:

```
<Window.Triggers> 
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded"> 
        <BeginStoryboard> 
            <Storyboard> 
                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00"    
                                Storyboard.TargetName="HomeWindows"    
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Window.Left)"    
                                By="-12"    
                                Duration="0:0:4" /> 
            </Storyboard> 
        </BeginStoryboard> 
    </EventTrigger> 
</Window.Triggers>
```

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply sir steve. how can i convert this to C# code? cause what i want to do is. let say i have two button. named Home and User. so if im going to click the home first at first load, it will slide and fade in came from the right side. and if im going to click the user button, the first child window that appears will slide to the left and fadeout and the next child window will slide and fadein. just like vice versa. and another thing, can i combine two animation at the same time.. like slide and fadein in C# code?  thanks... (sorry for being a newbie)

Comment: Unfortunately that's either going to be a bit of custom coding for the desired behaviour (different than the original storyboard question) or  require some playing around in a designer like Blend to get the desired effects.